# Is the neutron its own antiparticle?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter, neutrons, baryons

I have seen multiple claims that the neutron is its own antiparticle. However surely the antiparticle of the neutron would have a baryon number of -1 because it would consist of three antiquarks, each of which would have a baryon number of -⅓. I could be mistaken but I'm assuming that baryon number is flipped when taking antiparticles.

Comment: There is an [anti-neutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antineutron).

Comment: Are you sure you read the claim that a neutron is its own antiparticle, which it isn't (although I think early physicists wondered whether it might be)? You might have mixed it up with the debate, still unsettled, over whether the similarly named neutrino is its own antiparticle.

Comment: Poor question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antineutron

Comment: [Anti-neutrons, anti-quarks, isospin: What is observed and what is derived?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136542/anti-neutrons-anti-quarks-isospin-what-is-observed-and-what-is-derived)

Comment: There shouldn't be any claims that neutrons are their own antiparticle in any reputable physics source. Did you misread neutrino? It's currently unknown whether they are their own antiparticle ('Majorana neutrinos') or not ('Dirac neutrinos').

Comment: @dukwon Could you explain more in detail, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the antineutron has baryon number -1, because it is composed of antiquarks. The neutron itself is composed of quarks and has a baryon number of +1. It is made up of 1 up quark and 2 down quarks and the antineutron is made up of 1 anti-up quarks and 2 anti-down quarks.

Hence, the neutron is NOT its own anti-particle.

For more information on the anti-neutron, start with [its wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antineutron)

Comment: Small correction: 1 up and 2 down for the neutron :)

Comment: @CAF obviously my brain was lagging behind my fingers :-)