# If one is talking about antineutron production, what is the charge exchange?

Tags: antimatter, quarks, neutrons

In [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/134174/is-there-a-strong-evidence-of-antineutron-existance/134175?noredirect=1#comment274838_134175) was given the antineutron production in the way 
$$ p + \bar{p} \rightarrow n + \bar{n}. $$
Internet search gives one [source](https://publications.lbl.gov/islandora/object/ir%3A147263/datastream/PDF/download/citation.pdf) only where the charge exchange is mentioned. They talk about the "value for the $ \sigma (p + \bar{p} \rightarrow n + \bar{n}) $".

So I couldn't understand how does charge exchange works. Where comes the missing energy from? What is the full equation? Can one give later primary sources?

Comment: [An internet search](http://www.google.com/search?q=charge+exchange+reaction+antineutron) most certainly does produce more than one source, I'd say. Also, what's your question? There is a valid Feynman graph describing that interaction, and so it happens. What more do you expect?

Comment: You are reposting the same "question" after having been given the correct answers half a dozen times, already? I had to vote this down, sorry.

Comment: Are you asking, physically, where is charge being carried around in this reaction? Something like from one bound state, initially labelled $p$, to the other, initially labelled $\bar{p}$ via $W^+$ exchange maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest possible mechanism would by by the exchange of a virtual W$^+$ particle.

A proton contains (on average) three quarks, $uud$, while a neutron contains $ddu$. So to convert a proton to a neutron you need the reaction:

$$ u \rightarrow d + W^+ $$

Likewise an antiproton contains $\bar{u}\bar{u}\bar{d}$, while a neutron contains $\bar{d}\bar{d}\bar{u}$, so to convert an antiproton to an anti neutron you need the reaction:

$$ \bar{u} + W^+ \rightarrow \bar{d} $$

So when the proton and antiproton collide the proton decays to a neutron and creates a W$^+$, and the antiproton absorbs the W$^+$ and decays to an antineutron.

You point out, quite correctly, that the final state has more energy than the initial state because neutrons are heavier than protons. The extra energy comes from the kinetic energy of the proton and antiproton i.e. the kinetic energy of the neutron/antineutron is lower than the kinetic energy of the proton/antiproton by an amount equal to the mass difference.

But note that this is a charicature of what actually happens. The reality is that at the moment of the collision the proton and antiproton form some six quark system that then decays back into two or more particles in highly complicated ways. I say *or more* because the reaction will frequently produce $\pi$ mesons along with the neutron and antineutron. As before, the energy needed to create the $\pi$ mesons comes from the kinetic energy of the proton-antiproton collision.

At first glance it may seem a bit odd that the kinetic energy of the colliding particles can be used to create matter, but this is exactly what happens in particle colliders like the LHC. In the LHC the Higgs boson is 67 times heavier than the proton and antiproton that collided to create it. All the extra mass came from the kinetic energy of the collision.